# Как написать функцию на js, которая проверяет, был ли уже когда то введен параметр с определенным значением

Tags: javascript

```
function make(n) {
    var currentCount = [];
    return function (n) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentCount.length; i++) {
            if (currentCount[i] === n) {
                console.log('уже была')
            } else {
                console.log('не было')
            }
        }
        currentCount.push(n)
    };
}

var counter = make(); // (*)

counter(2)
counter(1)
counter(2)
counter(2)
counter(2)
counter(2)
```

Вроде написал, но как то криво работает(((

Функция не должна использовать внешние переменные.

Например
f(2) //false,
f(1) //false,
f(2) //true,
f(2) //true,
f(12) //false,
f(1) //true,

Comment: Вы очень скромно описали задачу. Мы хотим вам помочь, но тот контекст который вы нам дали не позволяет понять, что вы хотите сделать, где это применить и что уже пробовали сделать. Нажмите ПРАВИТЬ под своим вопросом и помогите нам помочь вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не думаю что это возможно в общем случае, потому что нужен алгоритм глубокого сравнения объектов (да их существует куча, но у каждого свои недостатки). Но можно сделать например если речь идёт про примитивные данные и/или передаваемые объекты нужно сравнивать по ссылке, тогда можно:

1. Вне функции объявить набор [new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
2. Каждый раз смотреть есть ли в наборе переданный параметр или нет
3. Если нет, то добавляем в набор значение параметра и возвращаем `false`
4. Иначе возвращаем `true`

Код:

```js
const memory = new Set();

const f = (param) => {
  if (memory.has(param)) return true;
  
  memory.add(param);
  
  return false;
};

const y = {z: 1};

console.log(1, f(1));
console.log(2, f(2));
console.log(3, f(1));
console.log(4, f(2));
console.log(5, f({x: 1}));
console.log(6, f({x: 1}));
console.log(7, f(y));
console.log(8, f(y));
```

Ну выводы 1-4 думаю не стоит объяснять. Выводы 5 и 6 - это `false`, потому что сравниваются объекты по ссылке, а не по значению, а при описании объекта, каждый раз создаётся новый объекта с новой ссылкой. Ну и выводы 7, 8 - `false` и `true` потому что мы записали ссылку в переменную и два раза отправили одну и ту же ссылку

Если нужно без внешнего параметра, то можно так (логика точно такая же, просто пользуемся обёрткой):

```js
const wrapper = () => {
  const memory = new Set();
  
  const f = (param) => {
    if (memory.has(param)) return true;
  
    memory.add(param);
  
    return false;
  }
  
  return f;
};

const f = wrapper();

const y = {z: 1};

console.log(1, f(1));
console.log(2, f(2));
console.log(3, f(1));
console.log(4, f(2));
console.log(5, f({x: 1}));
console.log(6, f({x: 1}));
console.log(7, f(y));
console.log(8, f(y));
```

Comment: Забыл дописать, что функция не может использовать внешние переменные, так да, с внешней переменной все просто.

Comment: @Madrid Добавил код

Comment: А уже понял свою ошибку, спасибо но я решил иначе)) function make(n) {
    var currentCount = [];
    return function (n) {
        currentCount.includes(n) ? true : false
        currentCount.push(n)
    };
}

var counter = make();

counter(2)
counter(1)
counter(2)
counter(2)
counter(1)
counter(3)

Comment: @Madrid Ваш алгоритм почти такой же как и мой, просто вы используете массивы, потому чем больше вы будете использовать свою функцию с разными значениями, тем медленнее он станет работать, а в моём случае независимо от количества элементов, поиск не будет отнимать время :) Если мой ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пожалуйста поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа :)

Comment: Да, ответ очень помог, но про время исполнения заинтригован. Почему Set лучше, это же что то типа массивов но для уникального хранения, или то что попало в сет, больше с таким же значением не запишется туда?

Comment: А, понял в чем профит)) Спасибо.